# Trying to hide a div using CSS

Tags: css

OK, simple question I know - but which of these is correct?

I am trying to hide this div:

```
<div class="notice important-message">

.notice .important-message {
    display: none
}
```

or - classes joined together like this:

```
.notice.important-message {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: *but which of these is correct?* --> test and see

Answer (score 3):

**.notice .important-message**

would select the element .important-message in this case:

```
<div class=".notice>
    <div class=".important-message"></div>
</div>
```

**.notice.important-message**

selects this:

```
<div class="notice important-message"></div>
```

so the second one would be correct.
Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more references.

Answer (score 0):

Second is correct. You can also do div.class1.class2 {}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<div class="hide">
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case **2 classes are on same node**

```
<div class="notice important-message">
```

so to access this code you can use (without space)

```
.notice.important-message {
    display: none
}
```

If these **2 classes are on parent child node**
that is

```
<div class="notice">
    <div class="important-message">
    </div>
</div>
```

then you can use (with space)

```
.notice .important-message {
    display: none
}
```